# How to solve wave equations with boundary condition $u_x(0,t)=h(t)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

\begin{align*}
u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0, x>0\\
u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0\\
u_x(0,t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2},t>0
\end{align*}

According to the textbook, I should look for solutions in the form $u(x,t)=F(x-ct)$ and impose the boundary conditions to get an ODE. However, I do not know how to impose the initial condition after these steps. Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158316/general-solution-to-wave-equation-of-half-line-with-nonhomogeneous-neumann-bound